# Calculating the time between a min() date and max() in YYYY-MM-DD format and converting to months

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm working with a pharmacy claims database in zeppelin and need to figure out the difference, in months, between the time a prescription was first given and the time when it was last given. The dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format. In short, the relevant data I'm working with is this:

```
user_id | date_service
++++++++++++++++++++++
1         2018-01-01
1         2018-06-01
1         2019-01-01
1         2019-12-01
2         2018-02-01
2         2018-07-01
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
patients | time_between
++++++++++++++++++++++
1          23
2           5
```

I tried building it out like this:

```
select distinct time_between, count(distinct user_id) as patients
from (
    select distinct user_id, datediff(max_date,min_date) as time_between
    from (
        select distinct user_id, min(date_service) as min_date, max(date_service) as max_date
        from pharmacyclaims
        group by user_id
    )
    group by user_id
)
group by time_between
order by time_between
```

I can't get this to run, but I also feel like there's a more efficient way of going about it

Comment: In what way doesn't it run?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for DATEDIFF may change depending on which DB engine you are using, but this will give your requested output in SQL Server. You don't need to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY clauses.

```
SELECT user_id AS patients, DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(date_service),MAX(date_service)) AS time_between
FROM pharmacyclaims
GROUP BY user_id
```

You also appear to be trying to build a histogram out of this data with a count of patients and the time between prescriptions. If that is the case, you can take the above query and add a count like this:

```
SELECT time_between, COUNT(user_id) AS patients FROM (
   SELECT user_id, DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(date_service),MAX(date_service)) AS time_between
   FROM pharmacyclaims
   GROUP BY user_id
) d
GROUP BY time_between
ORDER BY time_between
```

Comment: If I remove MONTH, I can get it to run in Zeppelin, but the output is all negative. If there a quick way around this?

Comment: Try changing the order of the dates: DATEDIFF(MAX(date_service),MIN(date_service))

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up doing and it worked, thanks! do you know of a way in Zeppelin to get the output in MONTHS instead of the DAYS default?

Comment: Looks like DATEDIFF() in spark only supports days. There is a function months_between(endDate, startDate) that should output in months.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs ?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
    (1,"2018-01-01"),
    (1,"2018-06-01"),
    (1,"2019-01-01"),
    (1,"2019-12-01"),
    (2,"2018-02-01"),
    (2,"2018-07-01")
).toDF("user_id","date_service")
.withColumn("date_service", date_format($"date_service", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
.groupBy($"user_id".as("patients"))
.agg(min($"date_service").as("min_date_service"), max($"date_service").as("max_date_service"))
.select($"patients", (datediff($"max_date_service", $"min_date_service")/30).as("time_between"))

df.show(false)
```

Output :

```
+--------+------------+
|patients|time_between|
+--------+------------+
|2       |5.0         |
|1       |23.3        |
+--------+------------+
```